# "No available cask" error for any cask I try to install

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

Well, I just updated my `brew` and installed `brew-cask` formula on my machine after a `brew tap phinze/cask` command. Then I did `brew cask install vagrant` to install Vagrant and it suddenly popped this out: `Error: No available cask for vagrant`. Trying to figure out what's wrong I noticed that it's failing for ANY cask, neither the `brew cask search` works.

Am I missing any step? Shouldn't it  work?

My `brew cask doctor` output:

```
==> OS X Version:
10.9.2
==> Hardware Architecture:
intel-64
==> Ruby Version:
1.8.7-p358
==> Ruby Path:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
==> Homebrew Version:
0.9.5
==> Homebrew Executable Path:
/usr/local/bin/brew
==> Homebrew Cellar Path:
/usr/local/Cellar
==> Homebrew-cask Version:
0.32.0
==> Contents of $LOAD_PATH:
/usr/local/Cellar/brew-cask/0.32.0/rubylib
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/vendor
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/powerpc-darwin13.0
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/universal-darwin13.0
/Library/Ruby/Site
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/universal-darwin13.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/powerpc-darwin13.0
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin13.0
.
==> Contents of $RUBYLIB Environment Variable:
nil
==> Contents of $RUBYOPT Environment Variable:
nil
==> Contents of $RUBYPATH Environment Variable:
nil
==> Contents of $RBENV_VERSION Environment Variable:
nil
==> Contents of $GEM_HOME Environment Variable:
nil
==> Contents of $GEM_PATH Environment Variable:
nil
==> Contents of $BUNDLE_PATH Environment Variable:
nil
==> Running As Privileged User:
No
```

Comment: It's buggy! They're tracking this issue here: https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask/issues/4032

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it was buggy (issue [#4032](https://github.com/phinze/homebrew-cask/issues/4032)) and they fixed this unwelcome issue with Homebrew Cask 0.33.0 release.

To update, just run `brew update && brew upgrade brew-cask` and everything should work fine. :)